# Weakly informative priors for "r.v. $\mathbf{x}$ is not close to $\mathbf{x}_0$"?

Tags: prior, heavy-tailed

Given some fixed vector $\mathbf{x}_0\in\mathbb{R}^d$, I want to put a prior on a random variable $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^d$ so that "it's not very close to $\mathbf{x}_0$". For the moment I put a Cauchy prior on $\mathbf{x}$, which is

$$
\mathrm{pdf}(\mathbf{x};\mathbf{x}_0,\mathbf{a})\propto\frac{1}{(1+\|\mathbf{x}-(\mathbf{x}_0+\mathbf{a})\|^2)^{\frac{d+1}{2}}}
$$

where $\mathbf{a}$ is the offset parameter. Are there any other "less heuristic" choices? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

"A prior that is not very close to a particular value" does not make much sense to me. I guess you meant the prior density does not accumulates most of its mass in a neighbourhood of $x_0$.  Maybe you can use a uniform prior on a suitable (large) set, in order to reflect vague/weak prior information. This sort of prior induces a posterior that is proportional to the likelihood in the support set.

In some cases you can use a uniform prior on the whole parameter space. However, you need to be careful and check that the posterior is actually proper with this sort of improper prior. If the parameters are regression or location parameters, then this sort of priors can be justified in terms of some formal rules such as Jeffreys or reference priors. If you need more specific suggestions, you will have to provide more information about your model.